# Initial camera intrinsic and extrinsic matrix and 3D point coordinates for Bundle Adjustment

Tags: camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction, vision, structure-from-motion, ceres-solver

I want to reconstruct 3d scene using multi rgb cameras. The input data has no camera calibration information so I want to use bundle adjustment algorithm (Ceres-solver) to estimate the calibration information.

Now I have already obtained pair-wise matched feature points but I find that the algorithm in bundle adjustment algorithm (Ceres-solver) also need initial camera intrinsic and extrinsic matrix and 3d point coordinates as input. However, I do not have this information and I do not know how to generate an initial guess, either.

What should I do to generate the initial camera intrinsic and extrinsic matrix and 3d point coordinates?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

Initial parameters are important to help the algorithm in converging to right local minima, and therefore to obtain a good reconstruction. You have different options to find the intrinsics of your camera(s):

- If you know the camera brand(s) used for taking the pictures you could try to find those intrinsics in a database. Important parameters for you are the CCD width and the focal length (mm). Try [this one](http://www.digicamdb.com/).
- Check [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) tags of your images. You can use tools like [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) or [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for that purpose.

You basically need the focal length in pixels and the lens distortion coefficients. To calculate the focal length in pixels you can use the next equation:

> *focal_pixels = res_x * (focal_mm / ccd_width_mm)*

If in any case you can't find intrinsics parameters for your camera(s) you can use the following approximation as initial guess:

> *focal_pixels = 1.2 * res_x*

Don't set the parameters as fixed, so focal length and distortion parameters will be optimized in the bundle adjustment step.

On the other hand, extrinsic parameters are the values of the ***R|T*** (roto-translation matrix) of every camera, calculated/optimized in the reconstruction and bundle adjustment step. Since scale is unknown in SfM scenarios, the first reconstructed pair of cameras (the ones with higher score in the cross-matching step) are generated from points projected on a random depth value (Z towards scene). You don't need any initial value for extrinsics or 3D point coordinates.